# Angular 2 promise/observable chain two events?

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if **observable** or **promise** can be used in the following use case in angular 2:

There are two asynchronized upload tasks. I'd like to know how I can detect both tasks are finished.

My upload task (implemented in **promise** but it's easily be changed to **observable** if needed) is like this:

```
myService.upload('upload1').then(() => {
})

myService.upload('upload2').then(() => {
})
```

How to chain these two events together in either **promise** or **observable** so that I know both tasks are finished? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`complete` is executed when all the source stream are closed.

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  myService.upload('upload1'),
  myService.upload('upload2').subscribe({complete: () => { ... });
```

if you want to set a max number of results to wait for

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  myService.upload('upload1'),
  myService.upload('upload2')
.take(2)
.subscribe({complete: () => { ... });
```

Comment: But got an error message:
***ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Rx***

Comment: Should be something like this: ***myService1.merge(myService2).subscribe()***. But this is not what I want. What I want is to get the last event.

Comment: Do you need the last event, or do you just want to know when the last event has happened, that's what `complete` is for (works only if the source observables are closed by the sender after the event)

Comment: Yes, I see. That helps (I call **complete()** to close in sender). Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use one of the [Combining Operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining) with observables. `Observable.zip()`, for example, works with promises...

```
Observable.zip(
    first,
    second,
    function (firstResolvedValue, secondResolvedValue) {
        return firstResolvedValue && secondResolvedValue;
    }
)
```

> `zip` accepts a variable number of Observables or Promises as parameters, followed by a function that accepts one item emitted by each of those Observables or resolved by those Promises as input and produces a single item to be emitted by the resulting Observable.

Answer (score 7):

Use [forkJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247310/angular-2-promise-all-with-rxjs/35247372#35247372), which is equivalent to $q.all from Angular 1.x (a and b are observables):

```
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([a,b]).subscribe(t=> {
        var firstResult = t[0];
        var secondResult = t[1];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Promise.all which returns a new Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the argument array have resolved.

```
Promise.all([myService.upload('upload1'), myService.upload('upload2')]).then(() => {
  // ...
});
```

Note, if your myService.upload method returned a Promise, rather than Promise, you could access the return values this way:

```
Promise.all([myService.upload('upload1'), myService.upload('upload2')])
  .then((retValue1, retValue2) => {
  // ...
});
```