# Promise.all() using RxJs.Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

I'm trying to implement Promise.all equivalent using RxJs Observable in angular 5, already tried all solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247310/promise-all-with-rxjs#new-answer), but none of it worked for me, the http requests in the chain simply not fired.

Here's the code I'm trying to execute:

```
let selected = [{channel: 1},{channel: 2},{channel: 3}];

postToDB(item: any): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post('/api/items/', item);
}

submitAll() {
   let submitAllSelected = selected.map((item: any) => {
      return this.postToDB(item).map((res: Response) => res.json());
   });

  Observable.forkJoin(submitAllSelected)
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.toaster.success('item saved successfully');
    }, (err: any) => {
      this.toaster.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }, () => {
     this.toaster.success('All items saved successfully');
    });

}
```

For some reason, and I not able to figure out, the http request are not fired, after submitAll() is called and the subscribe callback is not called.
The only way I did managed to make it work, is when I add .subscribe(cb)  or.toPromise() after postToDB() function.

This approach is working well with:

```
Promise.all(selected.map(item => postToDB(item).toPromise()).then(//do something);
```

But not with Observable.forkJoin/zip/concat or any other methods I've tried.
Will be great if someone can point me where I did wrong.

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was there:

> ```
> let submitAllSelected = selected.map((item: any) => {
>       return this.postToDB(item).map((res: Response) => res.json());
> });
> ```

`submitAllSelected` has type of `Observable<Promise<any>>[]`. It's should be `Observable<any>[]`

Correct way:

```
let submitAllSelected = this.selected.map((item: any) => {
      return this.postToDB(item).pipe(map(data => data))
});
```

If you use `HttpClient` no need to convert response to `json`.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/promise-all-using-rxjs-observable)

Comment: Ohhh wow! This actually worked! But I've suddenly discovered why it did not worked for me all the way... Appears, that the function I've used:  
    `postToDB(item: any)`
used a proxy function that was type-less, meaning that it did not returned Observable<any>, but typed as void instead.
Strange, since typing should not change the returned value anytime.